# String was not recognized as a valid DateTime (DateTime.Parse("16.10.2014"))

Tags: c#-4.0

When i Try to convert string to datetime, it thrown an error & it says that `String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.`

My code is below:

```
string dateString = "16.10.2014";
DateTime formattedDate = DateTime.Parse(dateString);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use [`DateTime.ParseExact`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parseexact(v=vs.110).aspx) to specify the format. That's pretty much always the solution when you know the format ahead of time:

```
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(
    dateString,
    "dd.MM.yyyy", // This might want to be d.M.yyyy - we don't know
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

The difference between `dd.MM.yyyy` and `d.M.yyyy` is how single-digit months and days are handled. Would July first be `01.07.2016` or `1.7.2016`? Adjust your format string to suit the data.

Note the use of `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` - this avoids parsing the date as if it's in a non-Gregorian calendar if your system culture happens to be one which uses a different calendar.